# OneDrive folder is missing in the Windows Explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive

Upgraded to the latest Windows 10 (Windows 10 Pro, Version 1930, OS build 18362.239), installed the latest OneDrive using OneDriveSetup.exe (19.123.0624.0005). However, I do not see the OneDrive folder in the navigation pane in the Windows Explorer:

[image: OneDrive folder is missing in Windows Explorer]

Tried several tricks with registry and gpedit.msc I found in the Internet, but this didn't help. How can I add the OneDrive folder to the Explorer's navigation pane?

Comment: Did you try going through the folder tree \users\username\onedrive ? I've had this happen to me once, but downloading/installing the setup program fixed it.,

Comment: @Larryc, how this can help? And what should I do - just open that folder in the Explorer? And I used OneDrveSetup.exe to install OneDrive, but this didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I was saying bring up the file explorer tool and go to c:\users\<your user name>\ and see if the onedrive folder is there. And I was also saying that I have seen this problem before, but for me, re-running the setup program fixed it. One other thought, you might try completely uninstalling onedrive, rebooting, then doing a fresh install. Good luck.

Comment: @Larryc, I moved my OneDrive folder to `D:`. Earlier I used OneDrive for Business. Perhaps, this is the source of the problem. I found remnants of this usage in the registry (mentions of the previous OneDrive folder as `D:\OneDrive - <name>`) and redirected them to the current OneDrive folder manually, but this didn't help.